# How to resolve a "driver failure" error in the Cisco VPN client connecting from a Windows 7 client

Tags: windows-7, vpn

I have recently upgraded my laptop from Windows Vista SP1 to Windows 7 Professional.

After the upgrade, if I try to use the Cisco VPN client to connect to a network, I get this message:

```
Secure VPN Connection terminated locally by the Client.
Reason 440: Driver Failure.
```

Prior to the upgrade, I was able to connect with no problems.

The version of the client I am using is 5.0.05.0290.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a website on how to install Cisco VPN on Windows 7: [How to (Successfully) Install Cisco VPN Client on Windows 7](http://weblogs.asp.net/bhouse/archive/2009/01/15/how-to-successfully-install-cisco-vpn-client-on-windows-7.aspx). There is even a comment at the end that someone using the same version as you has it working fine following the directions given (install the [Citrix DNE Update](http://www.citrix.com/lang/English/lp/lp_1680845.asp)).

Answer (score 0):

Some users have reported success by

1. Uninstalling Cisco VPN
2. Rebooting
3. Re-installing Cisco VPN

You could try these steps - it worked for me in Vista when my Cisco VPN client threw up the same error message some time ago.

Also, if you have a BSOD after doing these steps, I refer you to this article :

[How to prevent Cisco VPN client blue screening Windows 7 x32 Build 7000](http://blog.crowe.co.nz/archive/2009/01/16/How-to-prevent-Cisco-VPN-client-blue-screening-Windows-7.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to go through all that.

I have seen so many people go through this ridiculous process of uninstalling and reinstalling the VPN Client. Follow these and your life will be made a lot easier.

During the install or upgrade process, the uninstaller is not able to remove the old Cisco VPN LAN and thus creates a new one.

**Solution 1:**

1. Go to Start --> Settings --> Network Connections --> View Network Connections
2. On the listed Connections, you will find two Cisco Local Area Connections. The first will have a disabled Status, the second one will have a connected status.
3. Select the Cisco VPN LAN connection that has a connected status and disable it by right clicking and select disable

**Solution 2:**

1. Open Device Manager
2. Select Network Adapters
3. Uninstall the Cisco Adapter without the Disabled Icon (red top left icon)